# SwiftUI Layout Issue

Tags: swiftui

In this code I'm trying to get the horizontal scroll view with the image, title and description. However, when more content is added, my layout gets messed up, and the aspect mode of the image is unclear.

[image: Click to see my output for the moment]

```
import SwiftUI

struct HorizontalLayoutView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = LayoutsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    
                    let model = viewModel.horizontalLayoutModel
                    
                    ForEach(model.indices , id: \.self) { item in
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                            
                            //Product Image
                            
                            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: model[item].image)) { image in
                                image
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                                    .background(Color.yellow)
                            } placeholder: {
                                Image(systemName: "photo")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                            }
                            
                            //Product Title
                            
                            Text(model[item].title)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            
                            //Product Description
                            
                            Text(model[item].description)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        }
                        
                        .frame(width: 200)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                Spacer()
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .navigationTitle("Horizontal Layout")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}`
```

Are there any layouts like the horizontal scroll view in Amazon's shopping application?